# Python: How to resize an image using PIL module

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, image-resizing

I'm trying to resize an image to 500x500px but got this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1681, in save
     save_handler = SAVE[format.upper()] KeyError: 'JPG'
```

This is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('car.jpg')
new_img = img.resize((500,500))
new_img.save('car_resized','jpg')
```

Comment: try "JPEG" instead of "jpg" in your save function

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to set the format parameter in your call to the save function to 'JPEG':

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('car.jpg')
new_img = img.resize((500,500))
new_img.save("car_resized.jpg", "JPEG", optimize=True)
```

Comment: Does it still retain the entire image? or will it crop?

Comment: It will retain the entire image. Use `img.crop()` to crop

Answer (score 7):

Here is the solution:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('car.jpg')
new_img = img.resize((500,500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
quality_val = 90 ##you can vary it considering the tradeoff for quality vs performance
new_img.save("car_resized.jpg", "JPEG", quality=quality_val)
```

There are list of resampling techniques in PIL like `ANTIALIAS`, `BICUBIC`, `BILINEAR` and `CUBIC`. 
`ANTIALIAS` is considered best for scaling down.

Comment: Please take into consideration that ANTIALIAS is deprecated and will be removed from PIL in 2023 in favor of LANCZOS.