# How to download resized image using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib3

I am new to web-scraping ,I want a program that download images using bs4 and urllib3 but I want to download resized image ,I have previously used the following code

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE4wyTq?ver=c8e5&quot","image.jpg")
```

but this downloads image in it's real size I want to download this image with different height and weight
What can I do?

Comment: Unless the CMS / web application that manages this image online offers some query parameters you can add (along the lines of `&width=400&height=300`) to generate a URL which gets you directly what you want, you'll need to download the full image and resize it locally, then throw away the downloaded larger file. Or possibly you could find a web service that can resize it on the fly, but that gets into "asking for opinions" territory.

Comment: You need to use another library for this, like PIL, and process the image after you download it in its original size.

Comment: @fpietka how can I do that can you explain with code

Comment: you could follow the example there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631799/1481213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from skimage import io
import cv2
width,height = 'some_w', 'some_h'
req = io.imread("https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE4wyTq?ver=c8e5&quot")
cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", cv2.resize(req, (width,height)))
```